# Can we resize a QR-Code?

Tags: resize, qr-code

Does anyone know if we can resize a QR-Code easily by using a proper vector program OR, is the size information contained on that code, hence, we will not be able to resize without changing the code ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can resize as much as you want. The information is encoded in the pattern of the data, not in the size of the dots themselves. As long as a scanner can resolve properly between light/dark, the QR code should be readable at any size.

Comment: Nice. :) Let the ink expense begin. :)

Comment: As much as you want ? So I can resize it to a 1x1 pixel image ? I don't think so...

Comment: Quote: A Version 1 QR code will have 21 rows and 21 columns of dots and the version number will then increase by 1 for every 4 extra rows and columns – a Version 2 QR code will have 25 rows and columns, a Version 3 will have 29 rows and columns, right through to a Version 25 that will have 117 rows and columns. So you need at least as many pixels as you need rows, and that neglects the fact that the scanner may have a lower resolution, so won't be able to decode.

Answer (score 5):

Update 2016: If someone happens to need to upscale a QR code image in some sort of browser/webview - you might get away with a simple CSS property:

```
img {
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

This way the upscaled image stays sharp.

See a comparison here: http://codepen.io/erkkit/pen/GodxGX

Comment: great solution!

Answer (score 2):

For high resolution (vector image) QR code for printing/publishing:

1. Get your free QR code
2. Right-click-and-save OR PrintScreen the QR code
3. Open/insert it in Photoshop, crop the QR code, and save as *.psd file (default Photoshop format)
4. Open that *.psd file with Adobe Illustrator – and you get the vector QR code. DONE! :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't just re-size it that will make the edges blurry. You want it to have hard edges like MS-paint or the pencil brush in Photoshop. Open the file in Photoshop and go to IMAGE - RE-SIZE IMAGE and make sure **Nearest Neighbor** is selecting from the bottom drop down menu before you click OK

Comment: The requester asked about resizing a vector graphics version of the QR code. It sounds like your answer is about resizing a raster version of it, since Nearest Neighbor is a strategy for combining pixels in a bitmap to produce a smaller bitmap.

Answer (score -6):

You CAN'T, not with the free QR generators. Unless you do some Adobe Illustrator tweaks with Live Trace/Paint afterwards. The abundant free QR generators are a joke when it comes to publishing the QR code you need. Resizing an originally low resolution image (the previous comment) for publishing/printing purposes is the most rediculous statement I've seen in a while. The guy doesn't know what he is talking about.

Comment: It seems that the this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6179407/957997) says the opposite.

Comment: Well, get any free generated QR code, save it and use it for your brochure/pamphlet/flyer/catalogue - you'll see the grains - this will make your printed material look cheap and the QR code will be way less readable. Especially if you put more information into QR than just website address. What you see on your screen is not what is on paper, especially for commercial graphics. What Marc B answered does not make any sense - someone who doesn't know the topic should not give an answer.

Comment: I just posted a quick solution to get your QR code in vector graphic in 1-2 minutes. I do a lot of marketing and publishing and know what I'm talking about. ;)