# Hiding a watermark in an image that resist resizing

Tags: php, image, photo

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? I have tried embedding a qr code on the red channel of the pixels of the image, by making the pixels divisible of 7 but after resizing they change and the qr code gets corrupted. ( I've spread the QR code through the whole image, resulting in a total of around 30-40 qr codes on the image). My second attempt was to take 8x8 blocks of pixel and embed information on 8 bits (this process was longer and implied multiple things, but this was the basic explanation). But the information didn't resist the resizing again. Third attempt: As the image is basically a matrix I tried getting the fourier series (FFT) of every 8x8 block before and after resizing to see if it remains the same (which it has not). Any ideas of a stenography technique that resists resizing and change the image format? like from png to jpeg. Or at least just for resizing.

Thank you for your attention of my problem

Comment: Might want to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179376/can-we-resize-a-qr-code

Comment: Some idea can be found [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/256994333_A_novel_approach_to_digital_watermarking_exploiting_colour_spaces)

Comment: @Ôrel thank you, you're information seems quite useful. I will look into it